# why policy gradient theorm uses Q function in Reinforcment learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient-descent

The introduction of policy gradients algorithm states that policy algorithms are better because it directly optimizes policy without the need of calculating Q first. Why do they use Q in the equation then? How do they calculate the whole thing directly without calculating the Q function first?

[Policy gradient theorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8y0L.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about a data model, not programming. Questions like these might be on-topic on [Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: An alternative place to consider asking this question is on [ai.SE]. Please be sure to review the [help center](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) prior to posting.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why PG doesn't require calculating Q?

If you go a step further, you will see

[image]

This is because of that

[image]

Then you don't need to have a separate network to estimate Q (or) V values. You can calculate the return $G_t$ by executing your policy for an episode, and then apply Policy Gradient updates for your policy network parameters, i.e.

[image]

What described above is vanilla PG (REINFORCE), you can find the algorithm pseudocode below (credit: CMU Deep RL (10-703)):

[image]

Another good reference is [HERE](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2018/04/08/policy-gradient-algorithms.html#reinforce).

In addition:

#### Is this always true?

You can also refer to Actor-Critic described in the above post. While REINFORCE doesn't require calculating Q, if you can learn V in addition to policy, it will assist the policy gradient updates ==> Actor-Critic method.

The algorithm pseudocode for A2C is shown below (credit: CMU Deep RL (10-703)).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The real need of Policy gradients is not that it can remove the Q function, but to help in taking an action in continuous action space(or large action space). In continuous space, if we only use Q function, we have to send all actions in input to Q function estimator, and/or need to run an optimization to find the best action, for every state in the episode. It's computationally very expensive. To get rid of this optimization, policy estimator is used, which is learned with policy gradient. As well explained in the other answer, the Q function/ V function is not necessarily needed in policy gradients, but using so actually helps because

1. we can do directly do TD updates or use other methods than using full Monte-Carlo rollouts.
2. It further reduces variance in gradients if we use advantage function/ some more methods, as Monte-Carlo returns has a lot of variance.

By using policy network, you avoid running an optimization algorithm to find the best action at each step.

By using Q/V network, you aid policy gradient training.